# Can I install cyanogenmod from an internal SD?

Tags: cyanogenmod, external-sd, samsung-galaxy-ace-2

So far I am a regular user of Galaxy Ace 2, but I would like to upgrade it to CM 11. I found this page http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2555021 with step saying "Install the zip from **External** Storage" (emphasis is mine). The problem is:

- the (external) card is inserted
- I alread copied CM and Open Gapps (pico version) there
- yet when I reboot in the recovery mode I only have option of install from "internal sd card"

And when I browse internal sd card, there is no mount point for external card, so I assume it is not mounted at all.

Is it OK to copy the files to internal SD? Or what else should I do? Thank you for the help in advance.

Comment: Memory card will be listed as /microsd in recovery. Check it out :) BTW, yes, you can update from internal storage.

Comment: @GokulNC negative. It should be listed as either `/external_sd` or `/extSdCard`. It is safe to install from the internal storage though, as wiping `/data` in TWRP, CWM and Philz recovery does not implicitly wipe the internal storage unless you exclusively select it.

Comment: @GokulNC, no there is no such directory. Oddly, in main directory I can only see directories which names start with "." (dot) or capital letters.

Comment: @GiantTree Oops. Yeah.. I didn't remember that properly I guess ;)

Comment: @greenoldman What recovery is it? If it's a custom recovery like TWRP or CWM or Philz, check for an option named 'Mount' and mount the 'External SD' and 'Data' partitions in it.

Comment: @GokulNC, no, it is regular boot recovery from Samsung (stock one).